Why does Voyager use consumable hydrazine instead of reaction wheels that only rotate when moving the spacecraft?
Hydrazine can get used up. But voyager still has plenty of electricity for motors.

Reaction wheels also need to be desaturated.

By any chance did you listen to this podcast that appeared yesterday? https://shows.acast.com/the-tortoise-podcast/episodes/one-light-day-voyagers-long-farewell Heartily recommended either way.

@Oliphaunt I couldn't sit through the entire advertisement at the beginning. It was somebody shouting

@Ludo: Theoretically, you could do that by flipping them over 180 degrees, so they're spinning in the opposite direction relative to the spacecraft and the inputs needed to counter the external forces acting on the spacecraft now desaturate the wheels rather than saturating them.  I don't know of any spacecraft that've actually done this (presumably since it'd be mechanically-complicated), but it'd be a possibility for a spacecraft needing an extremely long endurance time.

@Vikki Many spacecraft are spin stabilized, so the need corrections are minimized to begin with. See, e.g. Pioneer and New Horizons which spun in cruse and despins for the science phase. Voyager is not spun.

@Vikki how would you flip a rotating reaction wheel without inducing all kinds of disturbing forces? Gyroscopes show us that spinning wheels don't like to be flipped.

@Ludo: Very carefully.

Voyager's electrical supply is not plentiful. Quite the contrary, it's one of their biggest constraints.
Radioisotope thermoelectric generators, which were used on both Voyagers, naturally degrade over time, both because the radioactive material slowly decays, and because the thermocouples become less efficient at converting their heat into electricity. The Voyagers started out with about 470 W of available power each; today, they have about 220 W.
Although some of their individual science instruments have failed, most of them are disabled because there simply isn't enough power to run them.
Hydrazine supply is not the issue with Voyager's thrusters. The main reason for failure of the orientation thrusters is clogging of injectors. There's no a priori reason to assume that reaction wheels would have a lower rate of mechanical issues (e.g., sticking or cold welding after long periods of inactivity) than thrusters.
The Voyager mission has a cut-off that has nothing to do with either electricity or consumables. This is the point, around 2036, when the probes are no longer able to communicate with the Deep Space Network. As they get further away, they need more powerful (and larger) ground stations to send and receive messages, and the process takes longer. The Voyagers already require a disproportionate amount of time on the DSN's largest dishes.

"The Voyagers already require a disproportionate amount of time on the DSN's largest dishes." ? ? Other than slew time, voyager probably uses less time than any other probe. It's bit rate is like 1200 baud, but it's not collecting from anything but the magnetometer and engineering status data.

@MissUnderstands Not anymore. The tape recorder hasn't been used for decades due to power and readout limitations. The data has to be received in real-time. As of this moment, Voyager 1 is occupying 3 34-meter dishes at 160 bits/second.

3 dishes, 1 at a time, right? 1 dish every 120 degrees on earth?

@MissUnderstands No, 3 at Madrid. I believe they're phased.

@MissUnderstands In addition, Voy 2 is only ever visible from Canberra because it is "south" of the plane of the Solar System putting further strain on Canberra. See Voyager Telecommunications pg 44. Right now, Voy 1 is occupying the 70m antenna at Goldstone at 160b/s.

At some time between now and 2036, the Voyagers won't have sufficient power to supply the few remaining instruments that are still active due to the ever dwindling nature of the RTGs. This will happen fairly soon, maybe a year or two or three.. At some point after this, JPL will have to decide whether to declare the missions over. What's the value of returning vehicle engineering data only? Even if the missions are  continued up to 2036, the hydrazine will last until 2040 or so, so hydrazine is not nearly as big a constraint as is electrical power.

@Schwern That's fascinating! And so is the link!

Looking at Hubble or Kepler I think we are lucky they were not using flywheels

@user20574 That was my point. JPL is still collecting some useful data from the Voyager satellites, but at 160 bits per second, it's not that much.  I would not be at all surprised if JPL keeps the downlink going to 2027 as 50 years is also an impressive PR thing, then says "mission accomplished" (which is true), and then shuts it down. Deep Space Network dish time is a precious resource.

@DavidHammen Guess is that they need a lot of science data (hours per day) because the fields and particles are so weak at that distance, they need to average a lot of readings. Engineering data, i.e. seeing if the thing is still alive, doesn't need that so checking in a few times a month is sufficient. The cost is much lower between the end of science and the point it dies.

@user20574, there's not much call for the 70-meter dishes.  Just about everything that isn't named "Voyager" uses the 34-meter dishes instead.

According to this Centauri Dreams article, reaction wheels are "both a lifetime and a power issue" with a lifetime "on the order of a decade".
Considering that the Voyagers launched 47 years ago and it took them 12 years to complete their original planetary flybys, the reaction wheels would have likely failed before the mission was complete.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Reaction wheels that are used in a mode where they are nominally non-rotating still suffer a phenomenon called saturation. Partly this is because rotations in 3D space are nonabelian, partly because sensors aren't always right, partly because of cross coupling, partly because it's not just attitude but also attitude rate that needs correction. Thrusters are needed to desaturate those saturated reaction wheels. The amount of propellant used to desaturate reaction wheels is typically much smaller than would be the case if a vehicle's attitude was maintained via thrusters only, but those thrusters are still needed.
The Voyager designers found that a thruster-only solution would suffice, even for an extended mission. They also distrusted the short lifetime of reaction wheels. A reaction wheel plus thrusters solution might have worked for the flybys, but it most likely wouldn't have worked for a long term extended mission as early 1970s reaction wheels were not particularly reliable over long periods of time.
